# C# Copy Google Docs Document via API

Tags: c#, google-api, google-docs

I'm wasting hours of finding out how to copy a Google Docs (Text document!)..

i tried multiple solutions but none of them worked.

Also the *documentId* != *fileId*, which makes the process a bit strange.

The code i've tried so far:

```
DriveService service = GetDriveService();
DocsService docsService = GetDocsService();
DocumentsResource.GetRequest request = docsService.Documents.Get(fileId);

var GoogleDocument = request.Execute(); //Returns the correct File

FilesResource.GetRequest getFileRequest = service.Files.Get(fileId);

var GoogleFile = getFileRequest.Execute(); //Error - see below
```

Error:

```
Google.GoogleApiException: "Not Found"

Inner Exception
JsonReaderException: Error parsing NaN value. Path '', line 1, position 1.

Diese Ausnahme wurde ursprünglich bei dieser Aufrufliste ausgelöst:
    Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseNumberNaN(Newtonsoft.Json.ReadType, bool)
    Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()
    Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read()
    Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadForType(Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract, bool)
    Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader, System.Type, bool)
    Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader, System.Type)
    Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(string, System.Type, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings)
    Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.DeserializeError(System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage)
```

fileId:

```
string fileId = "1N9YQSW_n5DAs1uchCz1GTnsIb-CmvhS-KnlsOWok-vs";
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You haven't added the error you get into your question(**please** don't post the error as an image, instead edit your question with the error text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a GetRequest instead of a CopyRequest. Also, you only need the Drive API to copy the file. From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Drive_1_1v3_1_1FilesResource_1_1CopyRequest.html) and the [Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/dotnet):

```
var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });
FilesResource.CopyRequest request = service.Files.Copy(fileId);
request.Execute();
```

Also, the DocumentId **is the fileId**:

[image]
Result from doing a [Get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) API Call:

[image]

Comment: I was using the Drive.v1 API, which seems not to accept the DocumentId as fileId, but got it working now, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should try the online request test by google. And there, you will see if the problem is coming from your code or not...
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/get?apix=true#try-it
When I type your ID, it is not working.

Comment: Well it is a file from his Drive, so unless it's completely public it won't work for another user.